# Display parent/child xml nodes in GridView

Tags: .net, xml, gridview

I have an XML form in the format

```
<DDCRData>
<role>
<name>CDH</name>
<adGroup>roles</adGroup>
<active>True</active>
<connectionNames>CDH0P</connectionNames>
<roleUsers>
  <user>
    <dbUserID>asuINBJvT4iGrrUgTcEKRPLzMzN6x6WBPtIjP+VYc6Y=</dbUserID>
    <dbUserPassword>x6JsTdhRcaNI+aFMeXfYkA==</dbUserPassword>
    <assignedTo />
    <checkOutTime />
  </user>
  <user>
    <dbUserID>AYufWjterIqgR4MA5wyO/L8AIVLcDQk1+HDvcqVCnrQ=</dbUserID>
    <dbUserPassword>GElP21V6jg7admUQW+hlZA==</dbUserPassword>
    <assignedTo />
    <checkOutTime />
  </user>
```

and am looking to output to a gridview the role name, and all roleuser attributes below it. There are 5 roleUser profiles per role, each held within the  node. I'm able to bind the top level information using the standard Dataset:

```
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml(MapPath("~/utility/LogFile.xml"));
        GridView1.DataSource = ds;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

but cannot seem to find a way to format the table the way i'd like (including the user info).

i.e. for each role within the xml config file.
Role Name
-assignedTo
-CheckOutTime

thanks for any and all information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured i'd update my post with the solution.
I created an xsd schema for the xml file and wrote two methods to populate a DataTable that I then used as the datasource for my GridView.

here's some relevant code:

```
userList = GetUsersFromRole(DDCRGroupName);
PopulateDataTable();


 public List<User> GetUsersFromRole(String DDCRGroupName)
    {
        List<User> usersBelongToRole = new List<User>();
        foreach (DDCRData.roleRow roleRow in config.role.Where(r => r.name == DDCRGroupName))
        {
            foreach (DDCRData.roleUsersRow roleuserrow in roleRow.GetroleUsersRows())
            {
                foreach (DDCRData.userRow userrow in roleuserrow.GetuserRows())
                {
                    User tempUser = new User();
                    tempUser.dbUserID = userrow.dbUserID;
                    tempUser.dbPassword = userrow.dbUserPassword;
                    tempUser.assignedTo = userrow.assignedTo;

                    usersBelongToRole.Add(tempUser);
                }
                return usersBelongToRole;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

      private void PopulateDataTable()
    {
        //populate datatable with all user information
        foreach (User user in userList)
        {
            DataRow row = userDataTable.NewuserRow();
            row["dbUserID"] = new AESEncryption().Decrypt(user.dbUserID).ToUpper();
            row["dbUserPassword"] = new    AESEncryption().Decrypt(user.dbPassword).ToUpper();
            row["assignedTo"] = user.assignedTo;
            row["checkOutTime"] = user.checkOutTime;
            userDataTable.Rows.Add(row);
        }
    }
```

Then in the aspx.cs page just a simple :

```
if ((roles != null) && (roles.Count() != 0))
        {
            DDCRData.roleDataTable table = roles.GetTable();

            GridView1.DataSource = table;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
```

hopefully this helps!